# Ggplot 2 is producing geombars with incorrect height using a density scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running a number of 2-variable categorical analyses on survey responses. Because some responses are much more common I'm using density scales with `geom_bars` so that the skewed data does distort differences.  I am very confused why the bars are summing to roughly 1.12 since the density scaling should force a total sum of 1 or 100%.

The data is 4600 survey responses. I'm not sure how to give an example of the data that would actually be helpful in reproducing the graphical disparity. It's not really worth talking about densities without a large sample... The data is something like this with each response of course having a lot of other variables.

```
data <- data.frame(pm = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), 
                   wt = c(12, 16, 86, 56, 10, 34), 
                   VA = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"))
```

This is a basic example of the code I'm using to graph one of those variables:

```
  plot <- 
  ggplot(data,aes(factor(VA),weight=wt,fill=factor(pm))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..density..,group=factor(pm)),
           position="dodge")
```

I have calculated the following table separately and these are the values I would expect to display in the graph.

```
                     Available  Not Available
Cash Ridership %     28.18      71.82 
Pass Ridership %     52.40      47.60
10-Ride Ridership %  45.80      54.20
```

Instead, the bars for cash are displaying at something like 32% and 80% instead of 28% and 72%. All of my other graphs made in a similar manner have the same problem but I didn't really notice until this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in `?stat_bin` it says about density  (emphasis mine)

> density of points in bin, scaled to **integrate** to 1

Moreover the default argument for `width` is `width = 0.9`. Therefore by default, the heights are scaled to sum up to `1/0.9 = 1.111`. So two possible solutions are:

**Changing width**

```
ggplot(data,aes(factor(VA), weight=wt, fill=factor(pm))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..density.., group=factor(pm)),
           position="dodge", width = 1)
```

**Rescaling density**

```
ggplot(data,aes(factor(VA), weight=wt, fill=factor(pm))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..density..*.9, group=factor(pm)),
           position="dodge")
```

Comment: I think rescaling density is the more elegant solution in my case as it maintains the separation between categories of bars on the x-axis. I was unaware of the default value of width.